# Getting API 2.0 open graph share to work as old 'feed' method

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

According to Facebook, the 'feed' method on a call to `FB.ui` is deprecated in version 2.0, and they suggest switching to Share method or the more complex Open Graph share.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  caption: 'An example caption',
  picture: 'whatever.png',
  description: 'A very simple way to customize the presented text'
}, function(response){});
```

But the actual 'share' method doesn't work in the same way 'feed' did, it just ignore most parameters which made fairly easy to customize how you want the share window to look (the image, the text, the title, etc).

And I can't find anywhere how to do this simply with Open Graph properties. Seems like I have to CREATE a story and then use its parameters? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create your own Open Graph story. It's enough to add the proper [meta data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/webmasters/) to your `<head>`. The dialog will pick up this data and display it accordingly. You can define the image, text, headline,... as you wish with these meta tags.

Comment: I need to able to customize the call on each button that appears on the page (such as products on an ecommerce website), and the meta tags are unique to the whole page, namely, the website itself.